# Functional Programming short circuiting

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I am investigating Functional Programming, namely `Arrow-kt` with `Kotlin`

my use case is as follows:

I want to perform an `Action` and return the associated `Reaction`

Both `Action` and `Reaction` have associated `Side Effects`

the sequence of events is

1). On accepting the `Action` immediately tigger the associated `Actions Side Effects`

2). Perform the `Action` and obtain the `Reaction`

3). Trigger the `Reactions Side Effects`

4). Return the `Reaction` result.

Additional factors to take into account when the Action is requested to be performed

a). When the Action has never been performed; complete the entire sequence, e.g. steps 1 - 4.

b). When the `Action` is being performed; short circuit the sequence so that steps 2 - 4 are not completed

c). When the `Action` has completed; short circuit steps 1 - 3 and return the `Reaction` result

The Side Effects mentioned above include `Logging`, `Analytics`, and `User Interface` effects.

I've a feeling that my requirement that the `Action` and `Reaction` Side Effects are triggered immediately means that a Functional Programming solution is not appropriate for my use case

The `Arrow-kt` presentations and blogs I have found describe how `Either` can be used to short circuit sequences based on Error Conditions being raised or using `Option` with `Some` and `None` to achieve the same type of behaviour.

What I am having difficulty with

i). is where to start????

ii). with four steps to complete, how to control/manage "short circuiting" so that either steps 1 - 4, just step 1, or just step 4 is completed

Is it possible to achieve the desired behaviour using Functional Programming?

Comment: As I understand it, you can't do that in pure FP, because pure FP doesn't _have_ side-effects…

Comment: @gidds Functional programming does have side effects. They're just isolated to a small part of your program so that everything not in that small part can easily be tested. A program with no side effects basically can't do anything. Outputting to the screen is a side effect. Getting user input is a side effect. Reading from a file is a side effect. Naturally if you can't display anything or get user input, it's worthless.

Answer (score 3):

The best starting point for your case is https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/error_handling/

If you'd like to do side-effects such as logging, the easiest thing you can do is make all of them `suspend` functions to mark them as impure. That way your whole program will be a chain of suspend function calls.

You haveto execute that first suspend function in the main, or the beggining of the business logic such as `Activity#onCreate`, or your `Controller`. To execute that first suspend function use `IO { myBusinessLogic() }.unsafeRunAsync { }`

Comment: Personally I don't like the convention of "suspend means impure" - there are plenty of things you'd put in a suspend function that is pure. Hashing a large ByteArray, for example, I'd put in a suspend function. Personally, I mark my side effects differently. Reading from a file, for example, belongs in an IO monad. Then you always know if you call a function has side effects because its return type is IO (for example).